# Haskell: How to tell if a type is an instance of class?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'd like to create a Template Haskell function such that:

```
$(isInstanceOf ''Read ''SomeType)
```

will result in either `True` if `SomeType` is an instance of `Read`, and `False` otherwise.

I tried to look at the result of `reify` and I think I'm looking for the contents of the `ClassI` constructor, but the documentation is somewhat lacking and I'm having trouble deciphering what I need. Can someone provide guidance on where to look to find the data needed to create the above function?

Answer (score 3):

Template Haskell already provides [a function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v%3aisClassInstance) that does *almost* what you want. It's there as of version 2.5, and prior to that I'm not aware of any means to look up instances at all.

The difference is that the existing `isClassInstance` function takes a `Name` for the class--which is what you get from something like `''Read`--but a `Type` to look for instances with. This probably makes more sense, because with a `Name` there's no obvious way to check for instances that require type parameters. For example, you wouldn't be able to check directly whether `[Int]` has a `Show` instance, or whether `Either String` is a `Monad` instance.

Note that a `Type` can be constructed almost as easily as a `Name` using a quotation, e.g. you could write something like `$(isInstanceOf ''Monad [t| Either String |])`.

Given the above, all you'd have to do is a bit of juggling to return a useful value from the splice, whatever you want that to be.